# How to list all combinations when they are grouped?

Tags: combinatorics

In a hypothetical game, 2 numbers of nine wins.
If I want to increase my chances, I would use combinations of 3.
There is 84 combinations of 9 numbers (1 to 9) 3 to 3, but only 12 combinations of 3 groups all combinations of 9 2 to 2:
1   2   3,
1   4   7,
1   5   9,
1   6   8,
2   4   9,
2   5   8,
2   6   7,
3   4   8,
3   5   7,
3   6   9,
4   5   6,
7   8   9,

There is some method, algorithm, technique, whatever, that I can use to list all 8407 combinations of 50 numbers (1 to 50) taken 10 to 10, where 5 numbers wins?
There is 2118760 combinations of 50 5 to 5, but only 8407 combinations of 50 10 to 10, to hit 5.
Can anyone please help me to LIST the combinations?

Comment: Could you please explain more clearly how this hypothetical game works? From what I understand you want to construct a set of triples from $\{1, \ldots, 9\}$ such that every pair $\{x, y\}$ occurs together in one of these triples.

Comment: That´s right!   In my question, I list all 12 combinations, but how to do if I have much more numbers, as a lottery with 50 numbers where 5 wins?  I want to try some combination of 50 10 to 10 to win 5, to increase chances...

Comment: This is a *[lottery wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lottery_Wheeling)* or *cover design*.  You can find some rather old links [here](http://thelotteryinstitute.tripod.com/wheels.htm)

Answer (score 2):

This type of problem is a specific instance of a covering design. A covering design is a set of three numbers usually expressed in the form $(v,k,t)$. This describes a collection of "blocks" of $k$-member elements chosen from a set of cardinality $v$ such that each $t$-member subset of $v$ appears at least once.

This [website](https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/) is an online collection of such designs where you can input your own $(v,k,t)$ and retrieve previously created covers that meet those parameters.

The only covering design in their archive with $v=50$, $k=10$, and $t=5$ can be found [here.](https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/show_cover.php?v=50&k=10&t=5) Unfortunately, this particular design has more than twice as many blocks as the OP wanted.

Comment: That final link actually has 19831 lines, and its title suggests at least 8820 are needed.

Comment: @Henry It was the only one the had for those parameters, but I didn't think to actually look at the number of blocks. Edited answer.